# Echo to screen session and to file

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I want to execute the following command:

```
echo $RANDOM 2>&1 >> test.txt
```

in this screen session:

```
screen -S test -X eval 'stuff "echo $RANDOM 2>&1 >> test.txt\015"'
```

However, instead of executing, it echoes the following:

```
echo  2>&1 >> test.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want the `echo` command to not just to save its ouptut to `test.txt`, but to actually show that output to the screen as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
screen -S test -X exec bash -c 'echo RANDOM=$RANDOM 2>&1 >> test.txt'
```

If you want to see the output and save at the same time, you can use `tee`:

```
screen -S test -X exec bash -c 'echo RANDOM=$RANDOM 2>&1 | tee -a test.txt'
```

Comment: What's `sh -c` ?

Comment: It will be run in cronjob, so I dont think that `tee` is a good idea

Comment: Run specified command in `sh` shell. The `tee` there is within the shell command (part of the `'...'`), the output will be visible only inside the `screen` session.

Comment: This will work if and only if `/bin/sh` is Bash. The *RANDOM* variable does not exist in Dash.

Comment: @Dennis true, changed it `bash`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ screen -S test -X stuff 'echo \$RANDOM >> /tmp/test 2>&1\n'
```

Or if you want to duplicate the output and manage it without `tee` by some reason

```
$ screen -S shell -X stuff 'echo \$RANDOM 2>&1 | while read; do printf "%s\\n" "\$REPLY"; printf "%s\\n" "\$REPLY" >> /tmp/test; done\n'
```

I assume you want redirect to file both `stdin` and `stdout` and your `2>&1 >> test.txt` was an accidentally mistake.

Comment: What it does? It pastes `echo $RANDOM > /tmp/test 2>&1` and executes it, but test.txt was not updated and got no output in actuall screen

Comment: @Ultra Surely it doesn’t update `./test.txt` – it updates `/tmp/test`. :) But what output you’ve expected if it was redirected to file by you. You may use `tee`, if you want to duplicate output.

Comment: @Ultra It was not obvious for me from your question that you want to duplicate output. And you’ve mentioned you would like to avoid `tee` – I do not see any reason for that, but of course it possible with GNU Bash. So I’ve updated my answer.